# Is this conversion script efficient?

Tags: php, performance, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

I wrote this piece of script to get the conversion rates from Yahoo API . What it does is I have a config file which has currency details I have to make an array of rates of all the currency present in the config here is my script .

Please review it and let me know if there is a better way to do this .

```
$cur = $this->parent->parent->config->conversionCurrencies;

    //$cur=array(11=>'USD/CRC');

    foreach($cur as $key=>$val){

        $get_cur = str_replace("/","",$val);echo "<br>";

        $code=file_get_contents('http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20(%22'.$get_cur.'%22)&format=json&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&callback=');

        var_dump($array1 = json_decode($code, true));

        $rates_array = array();

        $myaskRate = $array1['query']['results']['rate']['Ask'];
        $mybidRate = $array1['query']['results']['rate']['Bid'];

         $rates_array[$key] = round(($myaskRate+$mybidRate)/2,2);
        }
```

var_dump( $rates_array);

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I am new to this site man don't have much idea about code review thing

Comment: @VikramAnandBhushan as RC says, please move your query to codereview.stackexchange.com